# Lets encrypt ERR_CERTIFICATE_TRANSPARENCY_REQUIRED on chrome 68.0.3440.106

Tags: openssl, chrome, ubuntu

I have a VPS server under Ubuntu 17.10, and I have 2 domains, I have created a successful SSL certificate for the first domain 2 months ago,
Today I tried to install lets encrypt domain for the 2nd one, with

```
certbot --authenticator standalone --installer apache -d domain.com -d www.domain.com --pre-hook "systemctl stop apache2" --post-hook "systemctl start apache2"
```

Now on chrome, I got the invalid certificate with

```
NET::ERR_CERTIFICATE_TRANSPARENCY_REQUIRED
```

How can I debug and fix this error?
Thanks?

Comment: To debug this please check first what certificate you actually got in the browser. My assumption would be that this is not the current certificate from let's encrypt you expect since these use certificate transparency for a while already.

Comment: I have the exact same version of Chrome as you show (68.0.3440.106) and I don't get an error with this this URL. I get a freshly created certificate (10:54 GMT today) which also includes the certificate transparency information. Given that I have no problem with your site but you seem to have, the question is what certificate do you have in your browser.

Comment: Error is gone :), may be chrome cache issue?

Comment: Yes, seems like your chrome still had an old certificate  in its cache.

Comment: Ran into this today after a certificate in development failed to renew. Browser cached it, and asked dev to try in incognito mode once SSL was updated, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Add this header to your webserver (you need get a custom report-uri!):

```
Expect-CT: enforce, max-age=300, report-uri="https://..."
```